# Getting same result if I use > or != in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python. I am creating a program to printing Stars '*' in D Shape using for loop. I am using the following code.

```
for row in range(7):
    for col in range(5):
        if (col==0 or (col==4 and row!=0 and row!=6)) or ((row==0 or row==6) and (col!=0 and col!=4)):
            print("*", end="")
        else:
            print(end=" ")
    print()
```

In **if** statements first section, if I use row>0 and row<6, I get the same result. Now I am confused which operator I should use.

> col==4 and row!=0 and row!=6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

Since `row` iterates on `range(7)`, it can only assume the values of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.

- The condition `row != 0` applies to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.
- The condition `row > 0` applies to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.
- The condition `row != 6` applies to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.
- The condition `row < 6` applies to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

So in this specific case, you can use them interchangeably (however, I consider `>` and `<` to be more readable).

Answer (score 0):

Your rows go from 0 to 6 so:

- row != 0 and row != 6 --> everything except the outer two
- row > 0 and row < 6 ---> everything between the outer two

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `row > 0 and row < 6` and `row != 0 and row != 6` in this use case results to the same condition is because your `row` will only get the values of 0 1 2 3 4 5 6.

`row > 0 and row < 6` means 1 2 3 4 5

`row != 0 and row != 6` means 1 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 0):

Both are ok, but in either case, I'd chain:

```
0 != row != 6
0 < row < 6
```